# Java - Check If Argument Is Empty or Is Set?

Tags: java, arguments, isset

I'm very new to Java, and I'm trying to see if an argument being set is empty, and if so, to send a message to them, then kill the script. It's not appearing to work though, because I leave the argument empty, and I still will just simply not get my message, but it appears it's returning false.

```
public boolean onCommand(CommandSender sender, Command cmd, String commandLabel, String[] args){
    Player player = (Player) sender;

    if(commandLabel.equalsIgnoreCase("register")){
        if(args[0].length() == 0){
            player.sendMessage(ChatColor.GOLD + "You Did Not Set A Password! (Ex: /register mysupersecretpassword)");
            return false;
        }
    }
    return false;
```

**Final Solution**

```
if(args.length == 0){
```

**Not**

```
if(args[0].length() == 0){
```

Comment: Can you please provide how you are calling the method `onCommand()`? thanks.

Comment: @JavaDevil It's being used with Bukkit (A Minecraft plugin API)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is your checking the 0th position of args length.

```
if(args[0].length() == 0){
```

needs to be

```
if(args.length == 0){
```

In fact if your checking the 0th position of args length you will probably get a array out of bounds error.

Comment: if(args.length == 0){ was my final answer, thank you a bunch!

Comment: @Necro. you should accept the answer then =)   (click the tick)

Answer (score 1):

Consider this: `(args.length > 0) && (args[0].equals("") == true)`

> Happens when Executed from a *Shell Script* that has an *empty "$1"*
>   jim@U10netbook:~/workspace/MIDI$ ./Run

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# @(#)$Id MIDI filename.mid $
#
# Purpose: Run MIDI-Player.jar "midiFile"

# Run
# Copyright (C) 2016 James Elwood Love III - All Rights Reserved
# Permission to copy and modify is granted under the Bumpy license
# created 20160101
###################################################################
build=20160101
##########################
jar="MIDI.jar"
##########################
## INFORM ################
clear
echo    "\t $jar"
echo    " build $build \t JimmyLandStudios.xyz"
echo    "  Play $1"
##########################
## JAR ###################
java -jar "$jar" "$1"
##########################
exit $?
```